# having issues deploying grails project with cxf plugin onto WAS 8

Tags: cxf, websphere-8, grails-2.1

I am fairly new to **groovy/grails** and trying to deploy a **grails** app(WAR file) which uses **Grails 2.1.1** and **CXF plugin 1.0.1** to **WebSphere 8**.

This is the first time I am deploying **Grails 2.1.1** app to **WebSphere 8**, with CXF plugin for SOAP based Web Services and I am running into some issues. Same app deploys and works fine locally on **Tomcat** and I am able to get to my web service and access WSDL file.

Anyone had this issues or know what could be the issue, please help. Here is the stack trace:

```
Original Exception:

Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [sitemesh]: could not be initialized
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: CxfServlet
Error Stack: 
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not initialize DecoratorMapper : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:117) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.<init>(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:568) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:475) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:308) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:380) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:892) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3704) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659) 
     Root cause: 
     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:553) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) 
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1102) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.init(GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.java:48) 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:110) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.<init>(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:568) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:475) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:308) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:380) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:892) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3704) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)  a
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue with Grails 2.1.2 and WebSphere 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your *BuildConfig.groovy* to exclude the JAXB implementation and Apache serializer related libraries.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
            excludes ("serializer", "jaxb-impl")
    }
...
}
```

Then rebuild your war to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working fine on Tomcat, it sounds like a librairy conflict with IBM Websphere.

Be sure to configure the classloader to **Parent last** so that your application will override WAS librairy.

Comment: i did do that In WebSphere settings when deploying project. It did not take away my problem.